# Fadeout specific element after jquery ajax request doesn't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, fadeout

trying to fadeout an ul li after calling ajax request, return the id of the li but nothing happens..
any suggestions please?

```
$( document ).on( "click", "span#cancel1", function() {
            var a = $(this).find('a').attr("class");
            usrd = "<? echo $id;?>";
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '<? echo $baseUrl; ?>/urlforajax',
                type: "POST",
                data: { a: a, usrd: usrd },
                error: function(xhr,tStatus,e){
                    if(!xhr){
                        alert(" We have an error ");
                        alert(tStatus+"   "+e.message);
                    }else{
                        alert("else: "+e.message);
                    }
                    },
                success: function(resp){
    $('#msggt').html("<p class=\"preneff\">OK!</p>");
    $('#entry'+resp.output).fadeOut();
                    }
                });
     });
```

Comment: check `resp.output` value in console

Comment: As @Karna said, check output of: `console.log(resp.output);`

Comment: What is this resp.output? What is its value?

Comment: hi, i have for example <ul><li id="234"></li></ul>, the resp.output is the id 234..

Comment: @user3506378: dont you think , this `$('#entry'+resp.output).fadeOut();` should be `$('#'+resp.output).fadeOut();` as you need to fadeout the `li` which has a id `234` in above example

Comment: sorry, mistake, the id of li is entry234 so is <li id="entry234"></li>...the code seems correct but $('#entry'+resp.output).fadeOut(); doesn't work

Comment: well in that we need see if the selector was constructed properly or not. could you check what is returned from ajax call, `resp.output`

Comment: mmm..i don't know i think is something inside other javascript,this code is ok,  maybe bootstrap...however i've resolved refreshing asynchronously the page content whit jquery ajax on success..

Comment: ok for any errors check the browser console.  you could also create a jsfiddle, http:jsfiddle.net. i can have a look at it